# Getting last user update time for all tables in a database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

In SQL SERVER 2008 R2 I have 7 databases, each one with around 1000 tables.

I need to know wich tables were last updated by users. With some research I got to this code:

```
SELECT  OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS TableName,
                                  last_user_update,
                                  user_updates,
                                  index_id
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
WHERE database_id = DB_ID('SP3D_DB_RESEARCH_MDB') AND 
                    OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('CORECone3d')
GO
```

This returns only one result, since it's asking for last user updates on a specific table/database.

Is there any way to put it in some sort of loop so it iterate through all tables in a database and I can get which tables were last modified?

It does not have to be a query as result, it could be a simple text output.

I don't know if this matters, but I'm using MS SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO.

- UPDATE -

Based on Pradeep answer I get the following results, with TableName NULL

[image: query results based on answer]

Comment: Can't you just remove the `AND OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('CORECone3d')` ?

Comment: If I do this then it kinda show the result more like I need, but all values on TableName column are NULL then

Comment: read the 'remarks' section in this article, it should solve your null problem: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186301.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT  OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS TableName,
                              last_user_update,
                              user_updates,
                              index_id
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
WHERE database_id = DB_ID('SP3D_DB_RESEARCH_MDB')
```

Comment: Just so you know, instead of posting a new answer you can edit and undelete the old one.

Comment: This way it shows all last user updates on all tables, but I can't know which entry is for each table, because all values on TableNAme  are NULL this way

Comment: It is not possible to get tablename as NULL. Last_user_update can be NULL!!

Comment: @Pradeep I did update the question with an image of the results.

Comment: @RBasniak - try including object_id without object_name in select list and check whether it is null

Comment: This only works if the table updates happened to be on table columns included and/or defined by an index. If this works for you great, but if your users can update columns that are not included in indexes then you'll have a problem. I HIGHLY recommend implementing Change_Tracking. Super easy to get information like this.

Comment: @NickH. I just tested this but I am seeing an update to a non-indexed column is updating the last_user_update field.  Do you have anything that backs-up your assertion?