# SQL grouping results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to get the last time a table was updated by the users:

```
Declare @Collect Table (Name Varchar(100),last_user_update datetime)
Insert into @Collect
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'SELECT ''?'' as TableName, 
                                     last_user_update 
                        FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats 
                        WHERE database_id = DB_ID(''SP3D_DB_RESEARCH_MDB'') AND OBJECT_ID =     OBJECT_ID(''?'')' 
SELECT * FROM @Collect ORDER BY last_user_update DESC
```

The problem is that in the results, some tables are appearing 3 times (please see the image bellow)

[image: query results]

Since it appears that all tables duplicated have the same last updated time. Is there any way to group the results by the table name?

Comment: I think it is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26289609/getting-last-user-update-time-for-all-tables-in-a-database

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM @Collect ORDER BY last_user_update DESC`

Comment: @Arnand, it's not a duplicated. It's a follow-up of that question. Since it's a new problem I didn't want to edit that question to include a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values are indeed the same, you can just add `DISTINCT` to the query, and have it return unique results

```
SELECT DISTINCT ''?'' as TableName, last_user_update  ...
```

If you want to group after the fact, and only the last update interests you, you can do

```
SELECT TableName, max(last_user_update) as last_update 
FROM @Collect 
GROUP BY TableName
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Tables can have multiple indexes.  The dynamic management view [sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188755.aspx) will have separate entries for each index.

If you want to see the index name for each one, try this:

```
SELECT
    o.name as TableName,
    i.name as IndexName,
    istats.last_user_update
from sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats istats
inner join sys.objects o
    on o.object_id = istats.object_id
inner join sys.indexes i
    on i.index_id = istats.index_id
    and i.object_id = istats.object_id
order by
    o.name,
    i.name
```

Or, if you don't care about that and just want the last update time, you can group by the table name:

```
SELECT
    o.name as TableName,
    max(istats.last_user_update)
from sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats istats
inner join sys.objects o
    on o.object_id = istats.object_id
group by
    o.name
```

You can do an insert directly into your table with this query:

```
declare @Collect table (Name varchar(100),last_user_update datetime)
insert into @Collect
select
    o.name as TableName,
    istats.last_user_update
from sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats istats
inner join sys.objects o
    on o.object_id = istats.object_id
inner join sys.indexes i
    on i.index_id = istats.index_id
    and i.object_id = istats.object_id
where database_id = db_id('SP3D_DB_RESEARCH_MDB')
```

Also, I'm not sure what your goal is, but please understand that this view only has entries for indexes that have activity on them.  If an index is unused, it is not in this view.  The first access creates a row in the view.  The real interesting stuff on this view is the seek and scan information.

See this note from MSDN:

> When an index is used, a row is added to sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
>   if a row does not already exist for the index. When the row is added,
>   its counters are initially set to zero.

If your goal is to enumerate all the indexes and then show the last update date for all of them, you'll need to join to sys.indexes and then left join to sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats.